# How to subscribe and publish a object in CycloneDDS?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, data-distribution-service

I am using [CycloneDDS](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds) c++ build.

currently, I am able to publish and subscriber primitive data types.

[.idl](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds-cxx/blob/master/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldData.idl) file contains data structure

How to send an object or publish and subscribe an object in CycloneDDS?

**Edited** - object = both data ("state") and code ("methods")

Comment: An object can be seen as a combination of data ("state") and code ("methods"). Are you looking for a mechanism to distribute both of those? If this is not what you are looking for or what you mean by "object" then please clarify your question.

Comment: @Reinier Torenbeek yes I need to send an object --> both data ("state") and code ("methods").... as you have mentioned is it possible?

Comment: DDS is intended for distributing data. Distributing objects, as "their states and method implementations", is not described in any of the OMG DDS standards and not natively implemented by any of the DDS implementations, as far as I know.

Comment: @Reinier Torenbeek extra question... what is TypeObject in https://www.omg.org/spec/DDS-XTypes/1.3/PDF?

Comment: A TypeObject is essentially a type that describes a type. It would be too long to give a full explanation here as a comment. But even though is has "Object" in its name, it does not have much to do with your original question :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From above comment correct answer is

DDS is intended for distributing data. Distributing objects, as "their states and method implementations", is not described in any of the OMG DDS standards and not natively implemented by any of the DDS implementations